# page not found while sending request from postman to the laravel project

Tags: laravel

Here is my postman request
[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffrDN.png)

here is my api.php
[routes/api.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSQeR.png)

here is my controller
[class and method called from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn0YL.png)

Comment: Try localhost:8000/api/dmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because **app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php** has the function with body:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

You have a base path `/api` your route will be `/api/dmo`

Answer (score 1):

laravel by default adds a `api` prefix for routes that are in api.php file so you should check api/dmo